# Swift: Play Stop Button

Tags: ios, swift

I have an app of a moving button and it records every time a user click/taps on it. I need help creating a function for another button to play and stop the game.
this is the code so far:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var button:UIButton!
@IBOutlet var startButton:UIButton!
@IBOutlet var scoreLabel:UILabel!
var score = 0;
var timer : NSTimer!

@IBAction func processHit(sender:AnyObject){
    score += 1;
    scoreLabel.text = "Score: " + String(score);
}

func moveButton(t:NSTimer){
    let aWidth = self.view.bounds.size.width;
    let aHeight = self.view.bounds.size.height;
    let btnX = random() % (Int)(aWidth-60);
    let btnY = random() % (Int)(aHeight-60);
    button.frame = CGRectMake(CGFloat(btnX), CGFloat(btnY), 30.0, 30.0);



}

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    srandom(arc4random());
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.5, target: self, selector: Selector("moveButton:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true);
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Add the "play" button to your storyboard, then create an action outlet by holding control and clicking on the "play" button and drag it over to the view controller.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did this help you out?